# Conflicting character counts

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the number of characters in a given text file.

I've tried using both a scanner and a BufferedReader, but I get conflicting results. With the use of a scanner I concatenate every line after I append a new line character. E.g. like this:

```
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("sampleFile.txt");
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(reader);
    String totalLines = "";

    while (lineScanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = lineScanner.nextLine()+'\n';
        totalLines += line;
    }
    System.out.println("Count "+totalLines.length());
```

This returns the true character count for my file, which is 5799

Whereas when I use:

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.txt"));

 int i;
 int count = 0;
 while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
    count++;
 }

 System.out.println("Count "+count);
```

I get 5892.

I know using the lineScanner will be off by one if there is only one line, but for my text file I get the correct ouput.

Also in notepad++ the  file length in bytes is 5892 but the character count without blanks is 5706.

Comment: so what is your question exactly?

Comment: @PTBG My question is why do I get different answers using either a scanner or buffered reader?

Comment: Ok I've just checked and the difference is due to the scanner not counting '\r'. If I were to run this code on linux, would I get a different output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider the newline/carriage returns character in a text file. This also counts as a character.

I would suggest using the BufferedReader as it will return more accurate results.

Answer (score 2):

Your file may have lines terminated with `\r\n` rather than `\n`.  That could cause your discrepancy.

Comment: Yes, but I was told that the text file contains 5799 characters, unless my teacher calculated it incorrectly.